# KeePassX and Dropbox

Tags: encryption, passwords, keepass

I am currently using KeePassX on Linux to allow me to have a different strong password for each website. With this program there comes two major inconveniences: I lose access to everything in the case of a hard drive failure, and it is difficult to correctly synchronize all of my passwords across all devices (desktop, laptop, phone). My idea is to have the KeePassX file in a Dropbox synchronized folder with nothing else and to access that same folder from every device needed using their auto-updating client. Of course, I don't want Dropbox to have access to my passwords which I believe should not happen because the KeePassX file is or at least claims to be well encrypted. I would like to make sure that the file is well enough encrypted that if anyone I don't want to have my passwords gets ahold of my file from Dropbox (which can happen in several ways such as NSA, other similar agencies, rouge employee (either for personal benefit or for profit)). Keep in mind that if you are going to suggest a different option it needs to be both compatible with Android and Linux.

Comment: I think it is different enough since this question refers directly to Dropbox -- the other question mentions Dropbox but it is not the central focus.

Comment: I'd have to agree with schroeder and Jens. The solution is the same.